# Rubymine 6.0.3 Startup Error on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, installation, rubymine, wine, ubuntu-15.10

I am installing RubyMine on Ubuntu 15.10. I downloaded the .exe file and installed it using Wine installer. The installation gone pretty well.

But when I tried to run the RubyMine, I am getting an error. I am attaching the screenshot of the error.

I tried searching, I got answers related to Mac Os to remove the .jar extensions. But I couldn't find any regarding Ubuntu.

Anyhelp is appreciated.Thank you.[image]

Comment: Did you install a JDK?

Comment: Ya I did install the jdk 1.7.0_91

Comment: Ok, why are you not installing RubyMine 8 and JDK 1.8

Comment: Actually I already have JDK in my system. I am newly installing Ruby mine.  I have license for the RubyMine 6, so I am installing that.